# Receiving *.pdf files from PHP server in Java client application

Tags: java, php, pdf

Firstly, it's needed to be said that I have quite a short exprience with php, only writing some basic scripts, without using any frameworks, such as Zend.So, what I have to do is the following: add a part (let's say a module) to an existing php site, that will allow user to load pdf files from site(maybe it's better to say server) using Java desktop client. The client is actually a pdf reader, but it also should allow user to see his e-bookshelf consisting of books/articles which he has already subscripted to at site. The data should be ecrypted to be seen only by this user. That's why I'd like to hear some advice/ideas what is the best way to do such things as:

1. Write a php server-side part that will deal with taking files from server, encrypting them and sending to user. Especially I am concerned in which way it is better to send password for decoding at client side and how to send data from server, using sockets or url.
2. Request a file from Java desktop client. Here I mean if it's better to use sockets or call to url.
3. Implement a synchronization with state of shelf at site.
4. Implement an on demand downloading of selected book (selection happens at client side), if it has not been previously downloaded from site and stored at client side. Here a check of downloaded files should be provided. Also, I am interested in how to better make a request, for example, if it is better to send some kind of maybe XML file with book data that  should be parsed at server side and a response formed - here I mean sending book to client.
5. What encryption algorithm  it’s better to use. I think that keys would be based upon user login/password to access site and I need an algorithm for which libraries both in PHP( for encryption) and Java(for decription) exist. Maybe such idea of choosing keys is not so good, any thoughts are welcome.

I understand that it's quite a big question, so any ideas will be useful.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just use SSL and HTTPS for download.
Follow this example for the PHP side: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

For the Java side, follow this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

You may also need this for HTTPS:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip96.html